# Are these interaction lagrangians equivalent? $\mathcal{L}=(\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger) \phi^\dagger \phi \, (\partial^\mu \phi)$ vs $\mathcal{L}=...$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism

When solving a QFT problem, the solutions contained the step

$$\partial_\mu(\phi^\dagger\phi)\partial^\mu(\phi^\dagger\phi)$$
$$=\partial_\mu \phi^\dagger \partial ^\mu \phi^\dagger \phi \phi+2\partial_\mu \phi^\dagger \phi^\dagger \phi \partial^\mu \phi + \phi^\dagger \phi^\dagger \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi$$

However, expanding out each integration, in order to get the $2$ in the cross terms, the following interaction terms have to be equivalent:

$$\mathcal{L_{int}}=(\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger) \phi^\dagger \phi \,  (\partial^\mu \phi)$$ 
and 
$$\mathcal{L_{int}}=\phi^\dagger (\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger) (\partial^\mu\phi) \phi$$

Since a field does not commute with its derivative, and integration by parts does not bring from one lagrangian to another in any way I could see, how can I see that these lagrangians are equivalent? Following the schematic rules to find vertices for derivative interactions, they give the same vertex, but can it be seen directly from the lagrangian?

Comment: "*a field does not commute with its derivative*" [citation needed].

Comment: $\partial_0 \phi$ is the conjugate momentum, and so the commutator (at equal x) with $\phi$ is $\delta(0) \neq 0$. I don't know how/if the spacial derivative commutes so I didn't assume that it did, but would be interested in knowing.

Comment: In the Lagrangian all fields are classical aka c-numbers. They all commute (or anti-commute if fermionic).

Comment: Does this ordering have no impact on measurable quantities predicted in QFT?

Comment: If you wrote that comment up as an answer I would gladly accept it. It was the resolution to my question.